# Post content is cleared when updating

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-content

When I'm updating a post, its content is being cleared. What's wrong with the code below?

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'eb_save_subpage_data' );
function eb_save_subpage_data() {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'subpage' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_pl', esc_attr( $_POST['meta_input_title_lang_pl'] ) );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_en', esc_attr( $_POST['meta_input_title_lang_en'] ) );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_ru', esc_attr( $_POST['meta_input_title_lang_ru'] ) );

        remove_action( 'save_post', 'eb_save_subpage_data' );
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post->ID, 
            'post_title' => esc_attr( $_POST['meta_input_title_lang_pl'] ),
            'post_name' => sanitize_title( $post->post_title )
        ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', 'eb_save_subpage_data' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code:

```
add_action( 'save_post_subpage', 'eb_save_subpage_data' );
function eb_save_subpage_data( $post_id ) {
```

You have to use this action to add custom fields, default post data are saved automatically.

Comment: This makes no difference. I would like to update default post data like title - without content - but the content disappears somewhere.